# Regular expressions, is it always true that (r U s)* = r* U s* U (rs)*?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

> If r and s are any two regular expressions, then (r ∪ s)* = r* ∪ s* ∪
>   (rs)*.

I think this is not true. And I believe this would always be true :

> (r ∪ s)* = r* ∪ s*

I wanted to clarify this because of `(rs)*`. What do you think the right hand side would be if `r* ∪ s* ∪ (rs)*` ?

Comment: Counter-example to both: sr

Comment: @Pseudonym could you please elaborate?

Comment: `r` and `s` are regular expressions, try to generate `sr` with your proposal (It is neither from `r* ∪ s* ∪ (rs)*`). Try `rss` or `srs` as well.

Comment: Try $r=a$ and $s=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, and the regular expressions $r = a$ and $s = b$. Then $(r+s)^* = \Sigma^*$ whereas $a^*+b^*$ and $a^*+b^*+(ab)^*$ are both smaller.